# WPF DataGrid stealing carriage returns from stringbuilder

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a listener in my ViewModel that picks up on keystrokes. If there are more than 10 keystrokes within a second then it means it is from a swipe reader.

The swipe reader can be multi-lines and an external library works based on where the new lines are.

This code splits parts of the inputted swiped data into a separate entity and then I add it to a DataGrid where the user can then double-click a row which opens a pop-up so the user can edit the details.

The problem is when you do this, the focus is moved to DataGridCell, and then when a new card is swiped, I presume DataGridCell is consuming/handling these carriage returns because after this my string in my ViewModel shows identical data but without the carriage returns, which is then throwing an exception.

Is there any way that I can prevent the datagrid from consuming/handling the return key whilst still allowing users to select rows and for my viewmodel to then pick up on these carriage returns again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've found a working solution to this. In my code-behind I handle the DataGrid_OnKeyUp event and do the following:

```
private void DataGrid_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        TextCompositionManager.StartComposition(new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, this, Environment.NewLine));
    }
}
```

This checks whether the key is a return key, and then effectively sends an `Environment.NewLine` to the `Window`, it appears to work as expected now as the external library checks for \r and \r\n